# How to change CHARACTER_MAX_LENGTH of specific tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, alter

I have multiple tables in which I have columns that need to get linked through foreign keys, problem is that some of those columns have different character_max_length how do I update those specific tables?

An example select statement for a column:

```
SELECT column_name, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(column_name) LIKE '%MUNT%'
```

which gives me this:

[image]

now lets say I have to change all of them to 5

I've used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740935/convert-all-nchar-columns-to-nvarchar-columns-in-a-database-or-table) before to change the datatypes, maybe this can help a bit?

Thank you for considering my question

Comment: Which databe do you use (mysql, sql-server, oracle ..)?

Comment: my bad: i'm using sql server 2012, database version is 2008

Comment: @Alma Do, seeing that the select statement worked and gave me a correct output, I'd say yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Alter tabel tableName alter column columnName NVARCHAR(5)
```

Or try this more generic version:

```
use [YourDatabaseName]

declare @tn nvarchar(128)
declare @cn nvarchar(128)
declare @sql as nvarchar(1000)

declare c cursor for 
    select table_name,column_name
    from information_schema.columns 
    where TABLE_NAME not in (select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS)
    AND UPPER(column_name) LIKE '%MUNT%'
open c
fetch next from c into @tn, @cn

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = 'alter table ' + @tn + ' alter column ' 
        + @cn + ' nvarchar(5)'
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    fetch next from c into @tn, @cn
end
close c
deallocate c
```

Comment: I know this will work, but lets say I have 200 columns to change, I'm not going to edit that query 200 times. I would think to use a sub-query inside the alter statement, but that didn't work

Comment: ,thank you for your time and effort this helped me a lot.
A small tip for other people, do these changes and make sure all the datatypes and lengths are correct BEFORE making primary/foreign keys or you will have a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

You change the table definition, either through the user interface, or using [`ALTER TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)