# Images not displayed from Database ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, adrotator

I am trying to display advertisement using "AdRotator" and retrieving the images from Database. Unfortunately, the image is not appearing. I double checked the URL path and everything looks intact. Not sure what I had missed, maybe a second pair of eyes can help? Attached below are my codes and database schema.

**Advertisement_Banners**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Advertisement_Banners] 
(
    [AID]           INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageUrl]      NCHAR(100) NULL,
    [NavigateUrl]   NCHAR(100) NULL,
    [AlternateText] NCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Keyword]       NCHAR(100) NULL,
    [Impressions]   INT        NULL,
    [Width]         INT        NULL,
    [Height]        INT        NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AID] ASC)
)
```

**Advertisement_Banner** (sample data)

[image]

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<center>
    <asp:AdRotator ID="AdRotator1" runat="server" Target="_blank" 
         Width="100%" Height="50%" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" />
</center>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Advertisement_Banners]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[F12 Console Tab Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdHCz.png)

Comment: In the browser, press F12 to show the developer tools. There should be a "Network" tab that you can look in to see if any resources gave a 404 error, or perhaps some other error that will help you find where it is going wrong.

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, I followed as per what you said and updated in my source code. Please take a look.

Comment: I also double checked my directory and everything seems intact. But it seems like Visual Studio is not "capturing" my "Images" folder because when I upload a image (with c# code), my file explorer is updated with the folder, but not Visual Studio.

Comment: If you look at the MS article [How to: Display Ads From a Database Using the AdRotator Web Server Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms227550(v=vs.100)), you will see that they say to use the `nvarchar` type for the strings, not `nchar`. The latter will be padded with spaces, which is why you see all those "%20" in the URL.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now as to why I see those "%20" in the URL. Thank you for highlighting!

Comment: If you have a lot of columns that need to be converted, [Convert all NCHAR columns to NVARCHAR columns in a database or table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11741750/1115360) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I managed to solved the issue! Thank you.